# Unable to consume utility methods from a Sveltekit library Package

Tags: typescript, npm, svelte, vite, sveltekit

I'm creating a components & core library package to be consumed in another project.
I've been able to successfully export and consume the svelte components from the library package.
However, I'm unable to consume some utility methods exported from the library package.

Here is how my package.json  looks like:

```
"name": "@my-scope-name/my-package-name",
"version": "0.0.6",
...
"exports": {
        "./package.json": "./package.json",
        ".": {
            "types": "./dist/index.d.ts",
            "svelte": "./dist/index.js",
            "default": "./dist/index.js"
        },
        "./utils": {
            "types": "./dist/utilities/*.d.ts",
            "default":"./dist/utilities/*.js"
        }
    },
    "files": [
        "dist",
        "./src/lib/utilities/*",
        "!dist/**/*.test.*",
        "!dist/**/*.spec.*"
    ],
...
"type": "module",
```

and here is the index.js file:

```
// MediaQuery
export { default as MediaQuery } from './components/MediaQuery.svelte';
// NavBar
export { default as NavBar } from './components/NavBar.svelte';


// Utilities
export * as Utils from './utilities/utils';
```

And when try the following import statement:

```
import { NavBar, Utils } from "@my-scope-name/my-package-name";
```

it says that `Module '"@my-scope-name/my-package-name"' has no exported member 'Utils'.ts(2305)`

I'm not sure what am I doing wrong; I've followed the instructions from the documentation here: https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/packaging

Comment: Try adding `"main": "./dist/index.js"` to `package.json`.

Comment: @JoséRamírez adding `"main": "./dist/index.js"` worked! Thanks much.

However, Node.js documentation for ["main"](https://nodejs.org/api/packages.html#main) field states `When a package has an "exports" field, this will take precedence over the "main" field when importing the package by name.` So I'm wondering why didn't it just work with `exports` field specified in `package.json`?

Comment: Most likely a bug.  Where?  Dunno.  TypeScript, perhaps?  Vite?  I am far from qualified to find it, unfortunately.